# Orthonormalisation of the matrix other than Schmidt decomposition process

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $M$, I need a Orthonormal matrix which is row equivalent to matrix $M$.

I don't want to use Schmidt decomposition process due to some reasons.

I know Singular value decomposition (SVD). It works like given a matrix $M$, we can write $M = ABC$, where $C$ matrix is row -equivalent to matrix $M$.

Comment: $C$ is not necessarily row equivalent to $M$. In particular, if $M$ is $m \times n$ then $C$ is $n \times n$ so they can't be row-equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Gram-Schmidt process (also because it needs the product to be positive-definite) you can always use the *Lagrange's Algorithm*.

Let $(V,\phi)$ be a vectorial space over $\mathbb{K}$ with a scalar product on it. Then, for $i=1,...,n$ repeat these steps:

If $v_i$ is not an isotropic vector then $\phi (v_i,v_i) \neq 0$ and you define: $$(v_i)' = v_i - \sum_{j>i} \frac{\phi(v_i,v_j)}{\phi(v_i,v_i)}v_j$$

The result is a vector which still form a basis with the other vectors and it's orthogonal to the others after it. In fact, $\phi(v_i',v_j) \neq 0$ with $j>i$. Then you put $v_i'$ instead of $v_i$.

If $v_i$ is an isotropic vector you exchange $v_i$ with $v_j$ with $j>i$. If all the vectors are isotropic then you search a non-isotropic vector between the $v_j+v_k$ vectors, with $j,k \geq i$. If even these are all isotropic, then the basis is already orthogonal and the algorithm stops.

Comment: The scalar product, obviously!